# In Magento 2 use the after plugin in place order function, in the plugin i can't get the order id?

Tags: magento2, orders, plugin, di

in Magento 2 i extend the magento place order function [\Magento\Sales\Model\Order](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1059) but i did give the order id

```
public function afterPlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject, $result){
    $this->logger->info($subject->getId());
    $this->logger->info($subject->getIncrementId());
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: did you try $subject->getEntityId()

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-plugin-after-place-order-action-checkout-magento-2/ Check the blog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService**

```
public function place(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
{
    // transaction will be here
    //begin transaction
    try {
        $order->place();
        return $this->orderRepository->save($order);
        //commit
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
        //rollback;
    }
}
```

It seems order `place()` is done before it's saved, so it explains why you can't get ID

You'd better change your **after** plugin to **Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService** `place()` method, in the case you are using standard checkout

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-plugin-after-place-order-action-checkout-magento-2/ this is also useful for afterplace order